# Built-in category colors alternative

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a time chart which can potentially have many series, 20+ is not unusual. d3 comes with category10 color palette that is built-in and makes sense because the colors are different enough so you distinguish one series from another.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors

While the category10 palette is fine is there perhaps a more established (for the lack of a better word) array of colors that computer users have found as visually appealing and different enough?

My use case is displaying many series as colored lines on a time chart.

**UPDATE 1:**

An example of 10+ colors after the first iteration. Note that red and yellow colors are absent since they're often used for thresholds.

```
steelblue, orange, #339900, fuchsia, firebrick, deepskyblue, 
darkviolet, darkgray, #C0D800, #ff5800 , violet, #00d27f, #0057e7
```

Screenshot: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8YSG.png)

Comment: If you scroll down a bit on the page you've linked to you'll see a reference to ColorBrewer. These scales are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Lars Thanks for pointing it out. I saw colorbrewer when researching the subject. The problem is that lighter shades of each color's palette are barely visible. I think those palettes are more usable for treemaps and choropleth maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3` has support for [up to 20](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category20).  Once you get past that, picking visual appealing distinctive colors is virtually impossible.  The gold standard [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) only goes up to 12.  I once had a project which needed 48 for a line series graph.  After exhaustive research, I came up with:

```
[
 "#00A8F0","#C0D800","#CB4B4B","#4DA74D","#9440ED",
 "#4bb2c5","#eaa228","#c5b47f","#579575","#839557",
 "#958c12","#953579","#4b5de4","#d8b83f","#ff5800",
 "#0085cc","#c747a3","#cddf54","#fbd178","#26b4e3",
 "#bd70c7","#808000","#ffa500","#f280e0","#000080",
 "#ff00ff","#800080","#800000","#6ebf00","#edc240", 
 "#afd8f8","#cb4b4b","#4da74d","#9440ed","#3D96AE",
 "#4572A7","#AA4643","#89A54E","#80699B","#DB843D",
 "#DB843D","#92A8CD","#A47D7C","#B5CA92","#202020",
 "#a21764","#8ab438","#3a5b87" 
]
```

The non-devs on my team were never happy with it as some of the colors *were just too close to each other*.  I told them to go ahead and do better; they were never able to...

From the master of data visualization Edward Tufte:

> The often scant benefits derived from coloring data indicate that even
>   putting a good color in a good place is a complex matter. Indeed, so
>   difficult and subtle that avoiding catastrophe becomes the first
>   principle in bringing color to information: Above all, do no harm.

Comment: This is not bad at all: ![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/smgjmMK.png?1) although an array of green colors in the middle is too close.